# Converting .py to .exe using py2exe module

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, py2exe

I could successfully convert my py to an exe, but on running the exe it just opens and closes. The exe is supposed to ask for an argument to proceed.
This is not happening. What could be wrong?

I referred to this answer to [convert py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915462/how-to-convert-python-py-file-into-an-executable-file-for-use-cross-platform).

Comment: Either your script is running to completion, or it is producing an error and closing. I would suggest you add something like `raw_input()` to the start of the script, and gradually move it down the script to find where the problem is.

Comment: (Assuming that you're not using a GUI) I think the best way to start with this would be to open a command prompt and execute the script from there. Doing so prevents the window from being closed after the program finished. You should be able to see some output (an error message / traceback e.g.) which should help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution....Using [Pyinstaller](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script) helped me converting the .py to .exe easily....